# Getting ID attribute when event is triggered (elm v0.19.1)

Tags: events, event-handling, elm

I have two `div` html elements (with `contenteditable` attribute) and I would like to get de `id` attribute of the element when `keypress` is triggered (`onblur` event as well).

This is my current code (it does not work, I have added any comments):

```
module Mytest exposing (main)

import Browser
import Html exposing (..)
import Html.Attributes exposing (..)
import Html.Events exposing (..)
import Json.Decode as Json
import Debug

type alias Model =
    { div1 : String
    , div2 : String
    }

initialModel : Model
initialModel =
    { div1 = "test1"
    , div2 = "test2"
    }

init : () -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
init () =
    ( initialModel, Cmd.none )

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ div [ id "div1", contenteditable True, onKeyPress KeyPressed ] [ text model.div1 ]
        , div [ id "div2", contenteditable True, onKeyPress KeyPressed ] [ text model.div2 ]
        ]

type Msg
    = KeyPressed Int

update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        KeyPressed code ->
            let
                -- is there any way to use Debug.log without let block?
                a = Debug.log "div1 event" code
            in
                -- keypressed on div1 should be update div1 field model
                -- the same to div2
                ({model | div1 = String.fromInt code}, Cmd.none)

subscriptions : Model -> Sub Msg
subscriptions model =
    Sub.none

main : Program () Model Msg
main =
    Browser.element
        { init = init
        , view = view
        , update = update
        , subscriptions = subscriptions
        }

onKeyPress : (Int -> msg) -> Attribute msg
onKeyPress tagger =
  on "keypress" (Json.map tagger keyCode)
```

EDIT:

The following examples do not trigger the events in `div contenteditable`:

```
onInput : (String -> msg) -> Attribute msg
onInput tagger =
    on "input" (Json.map tagger keyCode)

onBlur : (String -> msg) -> Attribute msg
onBlur tagger =
    on "blur" (Json.map tagger targetValue)

onInput : (String -> msg) -> Attribute msg
onInput tagger =
    stopPropagationOn "DOMCharacterDataModified" <|
        Json.map alwaysStop (Json.map tagger (Debug.log "bbb" targetValue))

alwaysStop : a -> (a, Bool)
alwaysStop x =
    (x, True)
```

However, in javascript it works: http://jsfiddle.net/MBags/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unless there are additional constraints not evident from your example you could just add an extra argument to `KeyPressed` and pass the id through that:

```hs
type Msg
    = KeyPressed String Int

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ div [ id "div1", contenteditable True, onKeyPress (KeyPressed "div1") ] [ text model.div1 ]
        , div [ id "div2", contenteditable True, onKeyPress (KeyPressed "div2") ] [ text model.div2 ]
        ]

update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        KeyPressed id code ->
            -- Now you have the id
```

However, you probably shouldn't rely on string ids in the first place, since stringly typed data is very error-prone. Ideally you'd have separate `Msg` variants for each component:

```
type Msg
    = Div1KeyPressed Int
    | Div2KeyPressed Int
```

Or if you need a bit more dynamism you could use a custom `Id` type:

```hs
type Id
    = Div1
    | Div2

type Msg
    = KeyPressed Id Int

view : Model -> Html Msg
view model =
    div []
        [ div [ contenteditable True, onKeyPress (KeyPressed Div1) ] [ text model.div1 ]
        , div [ contenteditable True, onKeyPress (KeyPressed Div2) ] [ text model.div2 ]
        ]

update : Msg -> Model -> ( Model, Cmd Msg )
update msg model =
    case msg of
        KeyPressed Div1 code ->
            -- update model.div1

        KeyPressed Div2 code ->
            -- update model.div2
```

Comment: thank you. I guess I could use the first solution if there is not any better

Comment: do you know if it is possible to use `Debug.log` without using `let-in` block?

Comment: You'd typically use it in place of the value you're logging, since it returns the value it's given. E.g. you can use `(Debug.log "div1 event" code)` anywhere you use just `code`.

Comment: What would you consider a better solution?

Comment: I really need to update my model with the div (contenteditable) when is written (while keys are pressed)

Comment: And these solutions don't do that?

Comment: I have added more info in the main question, it is about any events that are not triggered on contenteditable elements with elm but they work in javascript.

Comment: Does the `keypress` event work as you expect it to, with either of the solutions in this answer? And is the problem that these other events aren't triggered at all, regardless of any `id` being passed along? If so, that seems like a completely different problem and should be posted as a separate question. If that is not the problem I'm afraid I still don't understand the issue. You should be able to use these same solutions with those events.