# Getting ID attribute when event is fired (subscriptions)

Tags: dom, events, elm

I have a subscription to calculate (`Calculate String` msg) something when user is writing on some divs (contenteditable).

```
subscriptions : CvModel -> Sub Msg
subscriptions _ = 
    onKeyUp (Decode.succeed Calculate) -- I need add the id element in message.
```

But, how I can get `id` attribute of the div where user is writing?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Getting ID attribute when event is triggered (elm v0.19.1)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60015829/getting-id-attribute-when-event-is-triggered-elm-v0-19-1)

Comment: @glennsl Here, I am using subscriptions so I can not use this solution

Comment: Why not? What difference does it make whether you refer to them element by a custom type value rather than a string?

Comment: Oh wait, I see what you mean. Why are you using the `onKeyUp` subscription instead of attaching an `onInput` event to the specific element?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The decoder that you pass to `onKeyUp` is decoding the event object, so you can extract the `id` property of the `target` element (much like [`targetValue`](https://package.elm-lang.org/packages/elm/html/1.0.0/Html-Events#targetValue)).

```
onKeyUp (Decode.at ["target", "id"] Decode.string |> Decode.map Calculate)
```

There's an example app at https://ellie-app.com/9MVn2Zsxptva1